# How do I properly import python modules in a multi directory project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

I have a python project with a basic setup that looks like this:

```
imptest.py

utils/something.py
utils/other.py
```

Here's what's in the scripts:

### imptest.py

```
#!./venv/bin/python

import utils.something as something
import utils.other as other

def main():
    """
    Main function.
    """

    something.do_something()
    other.do_other()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### something.py

```
#import other

def do_something():
    print("I am doing something")


def main():
    """
    Main function
    """

    do_something()
    #other.do_other()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### other.py

```
def do_other():
    print("do other thing!")

def main():
    """
    Main function
    """

    do_other()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

imptest.py is the main file that runs and calls the utils functions occasionally for some things.

And as you can see, I have commented out some lines in "something.py" where I am importing "other" module for testing.

But when I want to test certain functions in something.py, I have to run the file something.py and uncomment the import line.

This feels like a bit of a clunky way of doing this.

If I leave the

```
import other
```

uncommented and run imptest.py, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imptest.py", line 5, in <module>
    import utils.something as something
  File "...../projects/imptest/utils/something.py", line 3, in <module>
    import other
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'other'
```

What's a better way of doing this?

Comment: Test your snippets. Those extensions are going to mess things up

Comment: Would you mind posting a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of describing a hypothetical case?

Comment: "And all just works fine.": In that case, paste your actual code

Comment: Hey, I added more context/code. Please see if this is more useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is the path, Consider this directory structure

```
main
 - utils/something.py
 - utils/other.py
 imptest.py
```

When you try to import `other` using relative path in to `something.py`, then you would do something like `from . import other`. This would work when you execute `$ python something.py` but would fail when you run `$ python imptest.py` because in the second scenario it searches for main/other.py which doesn't exist.

So inorder to fix this issue, I would suggest that you write unit tests for something.py & other.py and run them using `$ python -m` (mod) command. ( **I highly recommend this approach** )

But.... if you really what your existing code to work without much modification then you can add these 2 lines in **something.py** file ( **this works, but I don't recommend this approach** )

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()) # Adding path to this module folder into sys path
import utils.other as other

def do_something():
    print("I am doing something")


def main():
    """
    Main function
    """

    do_something()
    other.do_other()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here are some references to get better understanding:

- [Unit testing in python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/unit-testing-python)
- [Absolute vs Relative Imports in python](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)

Comment: Yeah I arrived at some similar conclusions researching this.. I can run the utils. file with python -m utils.something and it doesnt throw an error. I have to figure out testing now. I just wanted to quickly test the utils script functions, without using "assert" and trying to determine the output of a function before using the function you know what I mean? Thanks for ur help tho.

Answer (score 0):

PavanSkipo has solved the `ImportError` using relative path [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65199222/13825658) but the files can then only be invoked as modules through `python -m utils.something` - whereas `python utils/something.py` will throw an error. The workaround using `sys.path` as PavanSkipo has mentioned in not ideal in my opinion <sup>1</sup>.

OP's use of the statement if `__name__=='__main__'` suggest that the files are meant to be run directly in some ways - perhaps as scripts <sup>2</sup>. In this case, we should use absolute imports and `pip install -e .`

Using this approach allows the files to be run both as a module and as a script on its own. In other words, all the following  `python utils/something.py`, `python -m utils.something` and `import utils.something` will work just fine.

---

Add `setup.py`

```
setup.py
imptest.py
utils/something.py
utils/other.py
```

Minimum content for `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name='utils', version='0.1', packages=find_packages())
```

After installing in development mode using `pip install -e .` you should use absolute import in `utils/something.py` like you do in `imptest.py`

```
import utils.other
...
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It is best that the codes being tested should reflect the state of codes being used.

<sup>2</sup> Ok maybe as entry points - but in that case it should have been installed as a package anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this. In order to be able to import a library and use it as executable you can do this. First, you should make `utils` a package. This means creation of `__init__.py` inside of it.

It's content should be this:

```
→ cat utils/__init__.py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

This will make the import statement work as `from utils import something, other` in `imptest.py` and also `import other` in `something.py`.

The final piece is as follows:

```
→ tree
.
 |-imptest.py
 |-utils
 | |-__init__.py
 | |-other.py
 | |-something.py


→ cat imptest.py
#!./venv/bin/python
from utils import something, other

def main():
    """
    Main function.
    """

    something.do_something()
    other.do_other()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

→ cat utils/something.py
import other

def do_something():
    print("I am doing something")


def main():
    """
    Main function
    """

    do_something()
    other.do_other()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

→ python3 imptest.py
I am doing something
do other thing!

→ python3 utils/something.py
I am doing something
do other thing!
```

This trick makes both import statements valid. It basically adds the `utils` directory path to the search path, regardless where it is located. As such, `import other` will work. The `__init__.py` makes the `utils` directory a [package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages);

Comment: Nah, running imptest.py fails with import other in something.py cause module other is not found in something.py.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add an `__init__.py` file in your main directory so python knows it's a package. Then you could add an import statement like so, from .other import function

Comment: I revised the post. I dont think this is exactly the solution I am after.

Comment: What if I dont want to import a function but the whole module? I guess thats not a good idea?

Comment: This doesn't solve - and has nothing to do with the ModuleNotFound error